# Why is there a common custom to place white coverings in shul for the High Holidays?

Tags: minhag, synagogue, high-holidays

I understand the reason why people wear a kittel (a white "coat") or white clothing on Yom Kippur, and why some people wear it on Rosh Hashanna as well. The common two reasons I have seen are that such clothes represents either angles or it is the shroud used to clothe the dead.

But, why do many shuls dress the Torah covers, parochet (ark curtain) and the Torah and chazzan "tables" in white as well? These are objects, so I can't see how this would be related to the same reasoning of angel or dead's clothes?

Comment: אם יהיו חטאיכם כשני כשלג ילבינו

Comment: @kouty Seems you are exactly correct. See the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[O.C. 610:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=150&hilite=) says that it has become a common minhag to place "pleasant" coverings in shul (he doesn't specify a color, though) on Yom Kippur.

Mishnah Berurah commentary #9 says that in explaining Isaiah 58 that says "For the holiness of G-d's honored" that this is specifically a reference to Yom Kippur. Since the verse mentions "Shabbat", we usually honor Shabbat by eating and drinking. However, as we cannot do this on Yom Kippur, we instead honor the day by covering the tables in clean cloths. (I assume that the term "clean" is synonymous with white, however, I guess one could, technically use any color that looks "clean".)

[This site](http://www.schechter.edu/kittel-on-the-high-holy-days/) mentions:

> As far as I know, the first to mention these customs is R. Ephraim
>   Zalman Margaliot (Sha’arei Efrayim, Galicia, d. 1820), who also
>   provides the most detailed description of these customs:
>
> The ritual objects — ark curtain, Torah mantles and table covers — 
>   should be beautiful and splendid, to honor and glorify the Torah. It
>   is customary to make these in many different colors.
>
> In honor of the High Holy Days, white ark curtains, Torah mantles and
>   table covers should be designated, for these are the days of judgment,
>   as is written (Isaiah 1: 18): “If your sins be like scarlet, they
>   shall be white as snow”. It was the custom to hang a white ark curtain
>   and cover the Torah scrolls used for the day’s reading in white
>   mantles.

Comment: It is important to note that the above website is of Masorti (or Conservative) denomination, which is contrary to Orthodox Judaism.